# Mocking imported function from other file when test and tested subject are in different files

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

- I'm using Jest testing framework.
- I'm going to test service `myService` from `myService.js` file.
- I'm creating separate file for tests, `myService.spec.js` in the same folder.
- Method `myService.myMethod()` uses helper `myHelper()` from `helpers.js` file.

Is there any possibility to mock somehow this `myHelper()`?

```
|
 -- myService.js
 -- myService.spec.js
 -- myHelper.js
```

`myService.js`:

```js
import { myHelper } from './myHelper.js';

export class MyService {
  myMethod() {
    const myVar = myHelper(42); // I need to mock this
  }
}
```

`myService.spec.js`:

```js
import { MyService } from './myService';

describe('my test', () => {
  it('should work properly', () => {
    expect(myService.myMethod()).toBe(24);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jest.mock(moduleName, factory, options)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) to mock `myHelper` module and `myHelper` function.

E.g.
`myService.js`:

```js
import { myHelper } from './myHelper';

export class MyService {
  myMethod() {
    const myVar = myHelper(42);
    return myVar;
  }
}
```

`myHelper.js`:

```js
export function myHelper(n) {
  return n;
}
```

`myService.test.js`:

```js
import { MyService } from './myService';
import { myHelper } from './myHelper';

jest.mock('./myHelper', () => {
  return {
    myHelper: jest.fn(),
  };
});

describe('my test', () => {
  it('should work properly', () => {
    myHelper.mockReturnValueOnce(24);
    const myService = new MyService();
    expect(myService.myMethod()).toBe(24);
  });
});
```

unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/61370607/myService.test.js (13.137s)
  my test
    ✓ should work properly (3ms)

--------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File          | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
--------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files     |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 myService.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
--------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        15.028s
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/tree/master/stackoverflow/61370607

Comment: You are perfect! Such a detailed explanation, and this works fine! I've read documentation, tried a lot, but I've missed this line: `import { myHelper } from './myHelper';`. Now I'll write better tests, thank you!